# Remove access to certain Database Records to a user using Custom Filter MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi guys I have various Database Models like this one

```
public class Trips
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
public .... // and finally
public string Group_Of_user { get; set; }
}
```

And my Identity profile is like this

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Group_Of_user { get; set; }
}
```

I had originally designed my models without and `Group_of_user`.My main aim is to restrict one `Group_of_user` from another `Group_of_user` records. So now everytime I have to check the record everytime the `User` is  accessing, editing etc etc with a if statement like the one below.

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
if (entry.Group_Of_user !=  user.Group_Of_user)
{
return HttpNotfound();
}
```

Is there any way either with a action filter or some code magic in Identity by which I can do this auto magically without inserting too many `Ifs` in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You just create a custom action filter, and then apply it to either your controller, action, or even globally via `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs`. However, this is best left as an excercise for you, as if you don't understand the mechanics, you won't understand how to fix problems, should they arise. Besides, the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) is actually pretty good on this.

However, before you go too far, this is actually a pretty poor way of restricting access, at least in the sense of maintainability. Instead of using some arbitrary string value, actually create a foreign key to an instance of your user entity or `IndentityRole`. Or, if you don't want to do either or those, at least create a full-fledged `Group` object and create an association with that.